# AFTER MIGRATION OFF PARSE: Can we make $hint queries or Secondaries against Primaries?

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform

I migrated my database off Parse month ago and we managed to optimize most of the queries so that some of them work 20X faster, but we have one unresolved optimization issue:

We have a quite large

```
{$query: {"_id": $in {array of ids}, "_updated_at": {$lt:...} , 
 $orderby: "_updated_at":-1}
```

against the _User collection at our Cloud Code (in a Cloud Function). The reason of slowness is that uses an index for `$query` the documents but not for the `$orderby` phase. That is a B-tree limitation (more is work as design).

To make the query use both an index for `$query` and `$orderby` we need to apply an index that starts with the `_updated_at` field instead of the `_id` field, but this index will be insufficient when the _id array is small-medium size. The recommended approach is to use a `$hint` when the array of `_id` exceed a value but since parse doesn't support that functionality we can't use it.

Another approach is to use Secondary Reads for that query but i am not sure if Parse Server supports it. Is there a kind of flag on Parse that allows a query to run against the Secondaries instead of the Primaries, using the `ReadPreference?` Could you help me with that?

Comment: Question has my +1. Both features are important in order the Parse server to better interact with MongoDB.  ReadPreference will allow read scaling by directing some queries on the secondaries. Hints will allow the application to instruct the database which index to use in some rare cases that the optimizer doesn't pick the optimal index.